# How to process barcodes from Datalogic Matrix scanner on Windows host?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, tcp, barcode-scanner

I'm about to purchase a Datalogic Matrix 300N fixed barcode scanner. I already downloaded and played with DL.CODE, this is the software to configure and emulate Datalogic Matrix scanners.

The idea is to collect and process the scanned barcodes on a Windows host with a Windows .NET C# application or service that has to be written by me.

As far as I can see now, the Matrix scanner could act as TCP Server and I can connect from my C# application (with TcpClient) to that Matrix TCP Server. However, there's no documentation or whatsoever available. Also I'm in doubt whether this is the right way to process barcodes in  an production enviroment.

What would be the right way to set this up? Is "Matrix TCP Server" the way to go, or should I look out for other ways of communication? (ID-Net? Ethernet/IP? Modbus? Profinet IO? HMS Fieldbus?)

Comment: How do you connect the scanner to your computer? What drivers do you have available?

Comment: Ethernet. This has nothing to do with drivers. I'm able to read directly from the TCP Server on the device, but I'm unsure whether this is the right way and I'm curious how this is done in "the real world".

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are manuals of matrix_300n_reference_manual and matrix_n_family_host_mode_programming in the Manuals & Technical Literature column of [Downloads for Matrix 300N](http://www.datalogic.com/eng/products/manufacturing-healthcare-transportation-logistics/stationary-industrial-scanners/matrix-300n-pd-659.html#download).

Likewise, there appears to be the DL.CODE Configuration Tool etc. in the Software & Utilities column.

If you can not understand with them, why do not you contact [Datalogic Technical Support](http://www.datalogic.com/eng/contact-us/technical-support-cts-8.html)?
or [Contact Us](http://www.datalogic.com/eng/contact-us-cts-4450.html)?

Comment: I read those documents, but there's nothing in it that answers my question or helps me setting up a host processing these barcodes. I was awaiting a response from Datalogic, but was looking for real world examples.

Comment: I see. Let's hope that the answer of Datalogic will come soon.

Answer (score 0):

You send a UDP broadcast to see which devices are present on a network and process the response. Once you have the device address you open a TCP/IP connection, hang async reads on it, let the scanner know via a send that you are listening, and process the async traffic received. While this is dependent on your receiving system., it is working in a client's production system at about 100 scans per second coming from multiple scanners.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple library that let you connect to a configured scanner and send commands to start reading and get back the read result:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DatalogicComHelper/

maybe it can help someone even if it's an old question